# Comparar se senha está correta

Tags: javascript, segurança, senhas

Como criar um JavaScript simples que peça somente que o usuário digite a senha 1234 para que apareça a mensagem senha liberada, se ele errar 3 vezes apareça conta bloqueada.

Meu código até agora:

```
var senha; 
var senha=1234;
senha=parseFloat(prompt("Entre com sua senha: ")); 

if(senha=senha==1234){ 
   document.write("Acesso Liberado"); 
}
```

Comment: Essa não é a forma correta de liberar acesso, se o usuário ver o código fonte certamente vai ver a senha

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Não faz muito sentido fazer isso em código real porque não dá segurança alguma mas é muito simples fazer isto:

```js
if (prompt("Entre com sua senha: ") == "1234") document.write("Acesso Liberado");
```

Uma senha é algo descritivo e portanto deveria ser um texto e não um número, não faz sentido transformá-la em número. Só precisa fazer comparação, não precisa atribuir nada. Sequer precisa de variável neste caso. E mesmo que precisasse não faz sentido criar na forma como criou. Procure simplificar seu código. E não use nada que não saiba porque está usando. Neste caso usou 6 coisas sem necessidade.

Para bloquear a conta quando erra 3 vezes:

```js
function validaSenha() {
    var erros = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (prompt("Entre com sua senha: ") == "1234") {
            document.write("Acesso Liberado");
            break;
        } else if (++erros == 3) {
            document.write("Conta bloqueada");
            return;
        } 
    }
    //aqui faz algo para o caso da liberação
}
validaSenha();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/PasswordValidation.js).

Comment: é só exercicio de uma aula...é que estou quebrando a cabeça e ainda nao consegui conciliar tudo...

Answer (score 1):

Como o [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) já mencionou:

> Não faz muito sentido fazer isso em código real porque não dá segurança alguma

Mas, tomando como exercício, dá pra fazer assim:

```js
errou = 0;
while (errou <= 3) {
  if (errou == 3) {
      document.write('Conta bloqueada');
        break;
    } 
    if (prompt('Digite sua senha:') == 1234) {
        document.write('Acesso liberado');
        break;
    } else
        errou++;
}
```

Respeitando o enunciado:

> criar um javascript simples que peça somente que o usuário digite a senha 1234 para que apareça a mensagem senha liberada, se ele errar 3 vezes apareça conta bloqueada

Comment: salvou minha vida obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer este exercício assim se quiser também:

> Se for digitado a senha 3 vezes **errada** a mensagem **conta bloqueada** é mostrada, senão a mensagem **Acesso liberado** será mostrada.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var respostas = [];

function obterSenha() {
  var senhas = prompt("Entre com sua senha: ");
  respostas.push(senhas);

  if (senhas == "1234") {
    p.innerHTML = "Acesso Liberado";
    p.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    p.style.color = "white";
    btn.disabled = true;
  } else if (senhas != "1234" && respostas.length == 3) {
    p.innerHTML = "Conta Bloqueada";
    p.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    p.style.color = "white";
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="obterSenha()">Senha</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, o ideal é você trabalhar com encriptação da senha, assim, mesmo nós desenvolvedores, que temos acesso ao código fonte, não poderíamos descobrir a senha.

Uma das formas seguras de fazer isso é usar a codificação SHA256, mas calma, é bem interessante o funcionamento e não é nada de outro mundo!

Ele embaralha a senha de um jeito que não dá para desencriptar, é uma encriptação de apenas um sentido, é impossível pegar o hash gerado(assim que chama) e achar o conteúdo original apenas com ele.

Ai você pergunta "úe e pra que eu vou querer isso?", ai que entra a parte interessante!

Você encripta sua senha com o Sha256 (por exemplo) e ele vai gerar hash(um pequeno texto), quando a pessoa digitar a senha na página, a gente vai encriptar a senha que a pessoa digitou, gerando o hash dessa senha digitada, e vamos pegar esse hash e comparar com o hash da senha original, se os 2 hashs forem iguais quer dizer que a senha colocada é a mesma! E **mesmo** se você tiver o hash (que é o caso de nós desenvolvedores que sabemos acessar o código fonte), não tem como saber a senha! Mesmo que você coloque o hash no lugar da senha, ele iria encriptar novamente o hash e geraria um hash diferente, e quando você fosse comparar não seria igual a sua senha.

Esse é basicamente o método que a maioria dos sites seguros faz, talvez eles usem outros métodos diferentes do Sha256, mas o princípio é o mesmo, no servidor deles não tem sua senha salva, e sim o hash dela, assim mantêm a sua privacidade, pois mesmo que alguém tenha seu hash, não dá para fazer muita coisa com ele. Existe ainda como gerar milhares de possibilidades e o hash de cada uma para ver se é igual ao seu hash, mas isso é muuuito demorado, e mesmo com computadores potentes pode levar dias ou mesmo semanas (se não meses ou anos) até achar sua senha, mas até lá o servidor já bloqueou o acesso depois de tantas tentativas.

Eu fiz um exemplo de como usar isso em uma página HTML, o código é bem simples, eu comentei cada linha para ficar bem fácil de entender, por isso está um pouco grande, vou colocar aqui:

```html
<!-- Chama a biblioteca Crypto-JS 3.1.2 da Google -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script>
// COMO COLOCAR SENHA
// 
// -Abra este site:
//   https://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator
// -Coloque sua senha dentro da área "Data"
// -Clique em "Calculate SHA256 hash"
// -Copie o "SHA-256 hash"
// -coloque na váriavel "SenhaOriginalCodificada" abaixo
// 
// OBS: A senha atual é "asd", não coloque a senha final aqui como eu fiz
var SenhaOriginalCodificada = "688787d8ff144c502c7f5cffaafe2cc588d86079f9de88304c26b0cb99ce91c6";

//Pergunta a senha
var SenhaDigitada = prompt("Digite a senha");

//Codifica a senha digitada
var SenhaDigitadaCodificada  = CryptoJS.SHA256(SenhaDigitada);

//Se a SenhaDigitadaCodificada for igual a SenhaOriginalCodificada
if(SenhaDigitadaCodificada == SenhaOriginalCodificada)
 
 //Se estiver certa
 {
  //mostra um alerta
  alert("acerto mizeravi");
 }
 
 else
 
 //Se estiver errada
 {
  //mostra um alerta
  alert("errrrrrrroooo, vai pro google vai..");
  //redireciona para outra página
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
 }
</script>


<b>Pagina normal</b>
```

Para você colocar o uso de 3 tentativas e depois esperar algum tempo, fica bem mais complexo, ai você teria que usar aqueles famosos cookies(eu usei a versão HTML5 deles, chamam [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)), e salvar no navegador a informação de bloqueio, e fazer a parte da contagem e do tempo que a pessoa pode tentar de novo, fica bem complexo, mas eu fiz também, é basicamente a mesma coisa que o código de cima, só que com umas adições, aqui está:

```html
<!-- Chama a biblioteca Crypto-JS 3.1.2 da Google -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script>
// COMO COLOCAR SENHA
// 
// -Abra este site:
//   https://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator
// -Coloque sua senha dentro da área "Data"
// -Clique em "Calculate SHA256 hash"
// -Copie o "SHA-256 hash"
// -coloque na váriavel "SenhaOriginalCodificada" abaixo
// 
// OBS: A senha atual é "asd", não coloque a senha final aqui como eu fiz
var SenhaOriginalCodificada = "688787d8ff144c502c7f5cffaafe2cc588d86079f9de88304c26b0cb99ce91c6";



/*Modelo de ERROS*/
 //Quantidade de erros permitida
 var QntErros = 3;
 //Se não tem qntErros cria no localStorage
 if (!localStorage.QntErros) {
   localStorage.QntErros = QntErros;
 }
 //Quantia de horas a bloquear a pessoa depois de consumir todos os erros permitidos
 var HorasPenalidade = 1;
 
 //Se não tem dataPermitida anterior salvas, salva 1 segundo atras no localStorage
 if (!localStorage.dataPermitida) {
   localStorage.dataPermitida = Date.parse(new Date())-1;
 }
 //Pega a data atual
 var DataAtual = Date.parse(new Date());
 //Pega a dataPermitida no localStorage
 var DataPermitida = parseInt(localStorage.dataPermitida);
/* modelo de ERROS*/



//Pergunta a senha
var SenhaDigitada = "";
if(DataAtual >= DataPermitida){
 SenhaDigitada = prompt("Digite a senha");
}

//Codifica a senha digitada
var SenhaDigitadaCodificada  = CryptoJS.SHA256(SenhaDigitada);

//Se a SenhaDigitadaCodificada for igual a SenhaOriginalCodificada E a dataAtual for maior ou igual a Permitida
if(SenhaDigitadaCodificada == SenhaOriginalCodificada && DataAtual >= DataPermitida)
 
 //Se estiver certa
 {
  //mostra um alerta
  alert("acerto mizeravi");
  //Reseta os erros
  localStorage.QntErros = QntErros;
 }
 
 //Se a dataPermitida estiver a frente da atual
 else if (DataAtual < DataPermitida){
  let date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.dataPermitida));
  let month = date.getMonth();
  let day = date.getDate();
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let hour= date.getHours();
  let min= date.getMinutes();
  let sec= date.getSeconds();
  let allDate = hour+":"+min+":"+sec+" "+day+"/"+month+"/"+year
  alert("Ixe amigo, só poderá tentar novamente em "+allDate);
  //redireciona para outra página
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
 }
 
 
 //Se acabaram os erros, agora só permite depois das horas de penalidade estabelecidas
 else if(localStorage.QntErros <= 1){
  //Reseta os erros
  localStorage.QntErros = 0;
  //Coloca o tempo de penalidade
  //localStorage.dataPermitida = Date.parse(new Date())+60*1000;
  localStorage.dataPermitida = Date.parse(new Date())+60*60*1000*HorasPenalidade;
  //redireciona para outra página
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  alert("Ixe amigo, você nao pode mais tentar durante um tempo");
 }
 
 
 else
 
 //Se estiver errada
 {
  //contabiliza o erro
  localStorage.QntErros = parseInt(localStorage.QntErros)-1;
  //mostra um alerta
  alert("errrrrrrroooo, você só tem mais "+localStorage.QntErros+" tentativas");
  //redireciona para outra página
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
 }
 
 
</script>


<b>Pagina normal</b>
```

Pesquise sobre esses termos, é uma área bem interessante!

Espero ter ajudado!